# How to connect from MongoDB Atlas version 4.4 to Mongo DB Shell?

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-shell

I copied the Mongo DB Shell connection string from Mongo DB Atlas and pasted to Mongo DB Shell. I got the following error.
Please enter a MongoDB connection string (Default: mongodb://localhost/): mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.h75mayj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username Kirushiraam
Please enter a MongoDB connection string (Default: mongodb://localhost/): mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.h75mayj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username Kirushiraam
MongoshInvalidInputError: [COMMON-10001] Invalid URI: mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.h75mayj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username Kirushiraam
Press any key to exit:

I'm expecting Mongo DB shell connect the Mongo DB Shell connection string to load the queries